# Shunt resistance VS Rogowski Coil in current measurement , which one is better?

Tags: current-measurement, resistance

Shunt resistance VS Rogowski Coil in current measurement , which one is better ?

Just for reference I want to create small circuit that measure the power , so which one I go for ?

UPDATE 1 : 
I'm measuring AC current 
Isolation is required 
Scale of current will be A to hundreds 
It will be a permanent part of the circuit

I'm going to make an Electrometer

Comment: Which is better, a sports car or a station wagon?

Comment: This is not a real question, at least in its current form.

Comment: @OlinLathrop what's the form you suggest for it ?

Comment: You need to provide more details. What sort of power are your measuring? (AC? DC? Pulsating?) Are there isolation requirements? What scale is the current under test? (mA? A? kA?) Is this a permanent part of a circuit, or an accessory like an external meter?

Comment: It's also recommended to allow several answers to appear and be moderated by up/downvote by the community before approving one.

Comment: Especially sinc the first one gave you a wrong answer.

Comment: @Madmanguruman 

Thank you for your effort , I'm new in the field ... 
I hope you find my update is valuable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rogowski coils measure only AC current. If you're measuring DC power, they are 100% not applicable to you. I've made use of several Rogowski transducers in my workplace, and have found that the coils can be quite fragile.

Shunt resistors can be used for AC or DC current measurement. For AC applications, it can be preferential to use a current transformer instead of a shunt, as it introduces less losses in the circuit under measurement (assuming your single-turn primary is of sufficient size).

Hall effect sensors are good for AC or DC as well, but the ones that I've used need + and - DC biasing, and can be cost-prohibitive at lower power levels.

Given your range of current, I suggest that a hall effect sensor will be your best bet in terms of accuracy, size and losses.